# Creating a TYPO3 Backend module with or without Extbase

Tags: typo3, extbase

The documentation contains this text.

> If you want to do extensive data modeling you may want to use Extbase templating. If you build a simple backend module it makes sense to work without Extbase.

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/BackendModules/TemplateClass/BackendTemplateViewWithoutExtbase.html

Why is it recommended to only use Extbase for backend modules with Extbase data modeling and not without? I would assume maybe performance reasons but I am not aware of using BE modules with Extbase to be particularly resource or performance hungry.

Also, using Extbase requires less code which makes the module easier to maintain long term - you reuse code from the core.

Is there any *real* *good* *reason* not to use Extbase for BE modules?

(I often use Extbase for backend modules and for plugins. I usually do not use the Extbase persistence functionality at all, I fetch content using QueryBuilder or from external resources. So far I never had a problem with this approach.)